is there a way to make a vnoremap act as a toggle?
In my .vimrc, I have the following visual noremap to remove semicolons from lines:
vnoremap ; :s/\([^;]\)$/\1;/g<CR>
I was wanting to change this so that, if a line does NOT have a semicolon, it will add one..  So in otherwords, I would like to make this behave as a toggle, so running it one time on a group of lines will remove semicolons, and running it a second time would add them.
Is this possible to do?

Of course it is possible, but it won't be as straightforward as your current mapping. Start with :help :map-expression, :help ternary, :help getline() and :help =~ and come back when you have something.

It can, but it would require sub-replace-\= and ternary as Romain hinted.
To simplify, I'll trim on the fly.
xnoremap <silent> ; :s/\(\S\)\s*$/\=(submatch(1) == ';' ? '' : submatch(1).';')/<cr>gv

We could also play with :global + getline('.')
